# Documenting fields in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

We're providing a public API that we use internally but also provide to our SaaS users as a feature. I have a Model, a ModelSerializer and a ModelViewSet. Everything is *functional* but it's blurting out the Model `help_text` for the description in the API documentation.

While this works for some fields, we would like to be a *lot* more explicit for API users, providing examples, not just explanations of guidance.

I realise I can redefine each field in a Serializer (with the same name, then just add a new `help_text` argument, but this is pretty boring work.

Can I provide (eg) a dictionary of field names and their text?
If not, how can I intercede in the documentation process to make something like that work?

Also, related, is there a way to provide a **full** example for each Viewset endpoint? Eg showing what is submitted and returned, like a lot of popular APIs do ([Stripe as an example](https://stripe.com/docs/api)). Or am I asking too much from DRF's documentation generation? Should I handle this all externally?

Comment: Have you checked the available options here: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/
I don't think any of them do exactly what you require of them, but some come close.

This Quora might be helpful as well! Lot's of suggestions; albeit not DRF specific. https://www.quora.com/What-software-powers-the-Stripe-API-documentation

We get fairly good documentation using Django REST Swagger, but not as good as Stripe; they're the gold standard!

Answer (score 0):

To override `help_text` values coming from the models, you'll need to use your own schema generator subclass and override [get_path_fields](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/schemas/inspectors.py#L274). There you'd be able to prioritize a mapping on the viewset (as you envision) over the model fields `help_text` values.

On adjusting the example generation - you could define a `JSON` language which just deals with raw JSON and illustrate the request side of things pretty easily, however, illustrating responses is difficult without really getting deep into the plumbing, as the default schema generated does not contain response structure data.